# The sugar mixture of my baklava did not melt

Tags: dessert

The baklava filling made with sugar nuts and spices, was harder. Why did this happen? I poured on the syrup mixture, hoping this would soften it up.  No luck.  It's like the sugar granuals crunch as your chewing.  Why? Baked at 350 for 45min. It was very brown.

Comment: Can you give a few more details of your recipes?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of baklawa. Ones you put the syrup before and after backing, and another one where you only put the syrup after baking.

**Put the syrup before and after backing**

This is the more uncommon / rare type of baklawa where the nuts resemble almost nut brittle.

This baklawa type is called "asiyyeh" (which translates to "the hard one"). In this method, when preparing the baklawa, you add roughly a table spoon of syrup for every cup of warm/hot nuts. After baking, you still add boiling syrup on top, and then drain it 2 minutes later.

You can see a video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNOW0Fw4Rpc&t=779s.

**Only put the syrup after baking**

In this method, you still put sugar in the nuts, or on the sheet that the nuts are going to be placed on. The goal of this sugar is to allow the nuts to stick just a little. This is more of a sprinkle of sugar here.

The difference between this method and the one above is the amount of sugar.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question asked, though.